# wrapAll() is creating double the divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div with two divs inside of it, like such:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

I have wrapped another div around 'child1' and 'child2' but it's appearing twice which I haven't been able to fix:

```
$(".child1, .child2").wrapAll('<div class="style"></div>');
```

Which is rendering out as the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="style">
       <div class="style">
          <div class="child1"></div>
          <div class="child2"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I actually want is the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="style">
     <div class="child1"></div>
     <div class="child2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I go about fixing this? I have tried numerous other methods of trying to sort the double-append.

EDIT: The issue was jquery was firing twice, I moved the code out of the existing file and into a new file. Once I did this the answers below all worked.

Comment: May i know in which browser you are testing.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/f4a75dh1/, check your original DOM by inspecting through dev tools, something might be triggering the the function twice.

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/q8fcrxy9/5/

Comment: Your are probably calling the function twice, there's no problem with the posted code

Comment: Works for me too. Sure you're not firing the function twice? Try sticking in a `console.log`.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle and show us your problem?

Comment: I will check to see if it's firing twice. I'm using Chrome @stanze.

Comment: Is your jquery code calling twice?

Comment: @foreverlearning, its working fine here.

Comment: @foreverlearning it's working fine for me. Issue not reproduce

Comment: Ok my jquery is firing twice according to the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran [this](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/wdrdyh3u/1/) in fiddle and it seems to work fine... ??????

You can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/wdrdyh3u/2/) though...

```
$(".container").each(function() {
    var ch1 = $(this).find('.child1');
    var ch2 = $(this).find('.child2');
    var st = $('<div class="style">');
    st.append(ch1);
    st.append(ch2);
    $(this).html('').append(st);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the code was running twice so I have fixed it now.

Comment: @foreverlearning Great!  Can you click the Check mark next to my answer on the left.  :)   And the Up arrow too if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
   $(".container > div").wrapAll('<div class="style"></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(".child1").next().andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='style'/>");
```

Try it...

Answer (score 3):

Change you markup little bit, (just add common class)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1 child"></div>
  <div class="child2 child"></div>
</div>
```

now use below code:

```
$( ".child" ).wrapAll( "<div class='style' />");
```